# How to submit a review for ItunesConnect automatically,or by cli?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

There are many apple web api about upload or validate a binary(or an ipa file).But I didn't find any web api on submitting a review.

Fastlane says it can do this but i can't find any infomation on [fastlane site](https://fastlane.tools/).And i have rare exprience on ruby,I can't find out how it work on this on its github.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no official way to do this via the App Store Connect API. You can do it with Fastlane. Check out https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/